# Jquery script show hide not working correctly in IE 8

Tags: jquery

new to all this and having searched here, am still pulling my hair out. Please be gentle.
I'm using Andy Langton's show hide accordion which functions fantastically in all browsers except IE 8 (and assume prior versions) In IE 8 clicking the read more toggle causes the drop down text to start to show a little(an looks like all the lines have been written on one line) then retracts, the toggle link remains the same.  Reading here of a similar problem I changed the js version number from jquery/1.3.2 to jquery/1.8.3  This shows the 'hidden text' as it should do, but the togglelink does not change, it remains on 'read more' when it should say 'hide'.

I'm assuming I'm on the right track as problem solved (albeit creates a different problem)So the question is what version of jquery should I be using?

#### Javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showText = 'Leer M&aacute;s'; //Read more
    var hideText = 'Ocultar'; //Hide
    var is_visible = false;
    $('.toggle').prev().append(' (<a href="#" class="toggleLink">' + showText + '</a>)');
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('a.toggleLink').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('visible');
        $(this).html(($(this).hasClass('.visible')) ? hideText : showText);
        $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
...
<a href="#" class="toggleLink"></a>
<span class="toggle"><br>
<span class= "ticktext"><span>
...
```

Comment: [http://jsbeautifier.org/](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Comment: @wirey the parens are in the string, no? It's strange, but it should work.

Comment: @couzzi ah yeah it should.. Looked really weird at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here

```
$(this).html(($(this).hasClass('.visible')) // <-- extra .
```

What you want is

```
$(this).html(($(this).hasClass('visible'))
```

unless you have a class of

```
class='.visible'
```

which you don't because you are toggling this `$(this).toggleClass('visible');` which results in

```
class='visible'
```

Though  I guess it doesn't make sense because it works in other browsers?

It does explain why it stays on read more.. because this always evaluates to false - therefore showText will always be shown

```
$(this).hasClass('.visible')) ? hideText : showText
```

Comment: Ah...that was the problem! Thank you and my hair thanks you too! I tried it with my original code and bipen's 'on', both work. Awesome response.

Answer (score 0):

since your are using jquery 1.8 , you have to use `on` delegated event for dynamically added element

```
$(document).on('click','a.toggleLink',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');
    $(this).html( ($(this).hasClass('.visible')) ? hideText : showText);
    $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, just tried it, functions correctly as a show / hide, but toggle link still stays as 'read more'